# Como hacer foco en una parte del DOM al dar click a un boton?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un texto bastante largo y cuando le doy click al boton "ver menos" me muestra solo unos renglones, pero el scroll no sube hasta esa parte del texto. probe con focus()pero no me dio resultado

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Lee [ask].

Comment: Favor brindar la información necesaria para poder generar la situación, como dijeron arriba ejemplo mínimo verificable, hacer pruebas y ayudarte lo más rápido posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcion javascript que buscas es `Window.scroll()`, la cual recibe dos parametros, la coordenada en X y la coordenada en Y, que representan el punto de tu documento donde se empieza a ver tu pagina. Puedes consultar mas profundamente en [la documentacion de mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll)

Comment: Gracias!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MarcoXXX Recuerda por favor marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ayudó a resolver tu problema.